# Present perfect in a past-tense context

Tags: tense, past-tense, present-perfect

> Presently I heard Pilot bark far below, out of his distant kennel in the courtyard: hope revived. Nor was it unwarranted: in five minutes more the grating key, the yielding lock, warned me my watch was relieved. It could not have lasted more than two hours: many a week **has seemed** shorter.
>   Mr. Rochester entered, and with him the surgeon he had been to fetch.
>   (Jane Eyre)

The sentence with the highlighted part is using the present perfect tense; yet, the previous and the next ones use the simple past tense. What's the reason for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jane here compares her experience of the particular past event with all the experiences of her life.

A couple of reasons which occur to me, more or less asking myself what reading the passage made me feel:

- Perhaps Brontë wishes to make it clear, unobtrusively, that the comparison is not something which crossed Jane's mind at the time.
- Perhaps she wishes to communicate that the moment was one which still stands out in Jane's mind as exceptional.
- Perhaps she has just entered into the part and come up, unconsciously, with one of those unemphatic moments of self-deprecating humour which make Jane such an attractive character.

The last seems likeliest to me, because that's how stories get told: by inspiration (or accident, if you prefer) rather than by contrivance. Brontë wrote Jane Eyre in the last generation before literature at the peak of the cultural pyramid became technologized: it was published the year after Poe's essay ‘The Philosophy of Composition’.

Answer (score 2):

If she had written "many a week **had** seemed shorter", it would be a comparison to all the weeks Jane had ever experienced up to this point in the story.

However, she wrote **has** instead.  To me, this sounds like Brontë is making a general statement; the author isn't just comparing it to Jane's personal experiences up to this point, but to how long weeks seem *in general*.